# docker redis sentinel failover failure

Tags: docker, docker-compose, redis, redis-sentinel

I am trying to test redis sentinel cluster failover, implemented with a docker-compose file and the communication is hostname based. To simulate failover I stop the current redis master container example `docker stop redis1`, what I expect is sentinel failover and one of the replicated redis instances is promoted as a new master, but what I get is the log below.

```
edis_sentinel-redis1-1     | 1:signal-handler (1648684795) Received SIGTERM scheduling shutdown...
redis_sentinel-redis1-1     | 1:M 30 Mar 2022 23:59:55.424 # User requested shutdown...
redis_sentinel-redis1-1     | 1:M 30 Mar 2022 23:59:55.424 * Saving the final RDB snapshot before exiting.
redis_sentinel-redis1-1     | 1:M 30 Mar 2022 23:59:55.430 * DB saved on disk
redis_sentinel-redis1-1     | 1:M 30 Mar 2022 23:59:55.430 # Redis is now ready to exit, bye bye...
redis_sentinel-redis3-1     | 1:S 30 Mar 2022 23:59:55.432 # Connection with master lost.
redis_sentinel-redis3-1     | 1:S 30 Mar 2022 23:59:55.432 * Caching the disconnected master state.
redis_sentinel-redis2-1     | 1:S 30 Mar 2022 23:59:55.432 # Connection with master lost.
redis_sentinel-redis3-1     | 1:S 30 Mar 2022 23:59:55.433 * Reconnecting to MASTER redis1:6379
redis_sentinel-redis2-1     | 1:S 30 Mar 2022 23:59:55.432 * Caching the disconnected master state.
redis_sentinel-redis2-1     | 1:S 30 Mar 2022 23:59:55.433 * Reconnecting to MASTER redis1:6379
redis_sentinel-redis2-1     | 1:S 30 Mar 2022 23:59:55.434 * MASTER <-> REPLICA sync started
redis_sentinel-redis2-1     | 1:S 30 Mar 2022 23:59:55.434 # Error condition on socket for SYNC: Connection refused
redis_sentinel-redis3-1     | 1:S 30 Mar 2022 23:59:55.434 * MASTER <-> REPLICA sync started
redis_sentinel-redis3-1     | 1:S 30 Mar 2022 23:59:55.434 # Error condition on socket for SYNC: Connection refused
redis_sentinel-redis1-1 exited with code 0
redis_sentinel-redis1-1 exited with code 0
redis_sentinel-redis3-1     | 1:S 30 Mar 2022 23:59:55.724 * Connecting to MASTER redis1:6379
redis_sentinel-redis3-1     | 1:S 30 Mar 2022 23:59:55.813 # Unable to connect to MASTER: Invalid argument
redis_sentinel-redis2-1     | 1:S 30 Mar 2022 23:59:56.129 * Connecting to MASTER redis1:6379
redis_sentinel-redis2-1     | 1:S 30 Mar 2022 23:59:56.170 # Unable to connect to MASTER: Invalid argument
redis_sentinel-redis3-1     | 1:S 30 Mar 2022 23:59:56.825 * Connecting to MASTER redis1:6379
redis_sentinel-redis3-1     | 1:S 30 Mar 2022 23:59:56.870 # Unable to connect to MASTER: Invalid argument
redis_sentinel-redis2-1     | 1:S 30 Mar 2022 23:59:57.176 * Connecting to MASTER redis1:6379
redis_sentinel-redis2-1     | 1:S 30 Mar 2022 23:59:57.224 # Unable to connect to MASTER: Invalid argument
redis_sentinel-redis3-1     | 1:S 30 Mar 2022 23:59:57.878 * Connecting to MASTER redis1:6379
redis_sentinel-redis3-1     | 1:S 30 Mar 2022 23:59:57.929 # Unable to connect to MASTER: Invalid argument
redis_sentinel-redis2-1     | 1:S 30 Mar 2022 23:59:58.231 * Connecting to MASTER redis1:6379
redis_sentinel-redis2-1     | 1:S 30 Mar 2022 23:59:58.305 # Unable to connect to MASTER: Invalid argument
redis_sentinel-sentinel1-1  | 1:X 30 Mar 2022 23:59:58.461 # +sdown master redismaster redis1 6379
redis_sentinel-sentinel2-1  | 1:X 30 Mar 2022 23:59:58.506 # +sdown master redismaster redis1 6379
redis_sentinel-sentinel3-1  | 1:X 30 Mar 2022 23:59:58.550 # +sdown master redismaster redis1 6379
redis_sentinel-redis3-1     | 1:S 30 Mar 2022 23:59:58.935 * Connecting to MASTER redis1:6379
redis_sentinel-redis3-1     | 1:S 30 Mar 2022 23:59:58.977 # Unable to connect to MASTER: Invalid argument
redis_sentinel-redis2-1     | 1:S 30 Mar 2022 23:59:59.311 * Connecting to MASTER redis1:6379
redis_sentinel-redis2-1     | 1:S 30 Mar 2022 23:59:59.352 # Unable to connect to MASTER: Invalid argument
```

**To Reproduce:**

**Files structure**

```
|./docker-compose.yaml
|./sentinel1/sentinel.conf
|./sentinel2/sentinel.conf
|./sentinel3/sentinel.conf
```

**docker-compose.yaml**

```
version: '3.8'
x-base: &base
  image: redis:6.2.6

x-base-sen: &base-sen
  image: redis:6.2.6
  command: redis-sentinel /sentinel/sentinel.conf 

services:
  redis1:
    <<: *base
    hostname: redis1
    command: redis-server  --replica-announce-ip redis1

  redis2:
    <<: *base
    hostname: redis2
    command: redis-server --slaveof redis1 6379 --replica-announce-ip redis2

  redis3:
    <<: *base
    hostname: redis3
    command: redis-server --slaveof redis1 6379 --replica-announce-ip redis3

  sentinel1:
    <<: *base-sen
    hostname: sentinel1
    volumes:
    - type: bind
      source: sentinel1
      target: /sentinel

  sentinel2:
    <<: *base-sen
    hostname: sentinel2
    volumes:
    - type: bind
      source: sentinel2
      target: /sentinel

  sentinel3:
    <<: *base-sen
    hostname: sentinel3
    volumes:
    - type: bind
      source: sentinel3
      target: /sentinel
```

**sentinel1/sentinel.conf**

```
port 26379

dir /tmp

sentinel monitor redismaster redis1 6379 2
sentinel down-after-milliseconds redismaster 3000 
sentinel parallel-syncs redismaster 1
sentinel failover-timeout redismaster 6000
sentinel resolve-hostnames yes
sentinel announce-hostnames yes
sentinel announce-ip sentinel1
```

**sentinel2/sentinel.conf**

```
port 26379

dir /tmp

sentinel monitor redismaster redis1 6379 2
sentinel down-after-milliseconds redismaster 3000 
sentinel parallel-syncs redismaster 1
sentinel failover-timeout redismaster 6000
sentinel resolve-hostnames yes
sentinel announce-hostnames yes
sentinel announce-ip sentinel2
```

**sentinel3/sentinel.conf**

```
port 26379

dir /tmp

sentinel monitor redismaster redis1 6379 2
sentinel down-after-milliseconds redismaster 3000 
sentinel parallel-syncs redismaster 1
sentinel failover-timeout redismaster 6000
sentinel resolve-hostnames yes
sentinel announce-hostnames yes
sentinel announce-ip sentinel3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

changed image to `redis:7.0-rc2` and it worked